# how to use _infile_ in SAS to delete lines in a hierarchical prog

Tags: sas, delete-row

Trying a hierarchical prg in SAS Studio

I'm trying to retain the Buyer code and Vendor with a retain statement as "headers" and read in the detail with a if/then conditional statements, but cannot figure out a way to do this with the repeating labels in the way. How can I use *infile* to delete the repeating/imbedded labels?

```
oucher  Vendor      Vendor  Payment     Po Nb       Total   Total       PO  Inv 
Nbr I   nv Nbr/Ln       Inv Dat e Due Date  Inv Amt Ln Nb       Rec'd   Dist    Inv'd   Price   Price   St
------------    ----------  --- ----------- ----------- --------------  --------    -   --------------- --------    ---------   --------------  ------------    ---
Buyer Code: BLS BETTIE  SM  ITH                                     
Vendor: 8444 DAT    EX- OHMEDA                                      
762100  62245094    /   03/04/15    42097   2142.46 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 2142.46 Q
762101  62243752    /   03/01/15    42094   16001.6 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 16001.6 B
762690  62247150    /   03/07/15    42100   1790.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1790.38 Q
762691  62246387    /   03/06/15    42099   1520.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1520.38 Q
762692  62246386    /   03/06/15    42099   1070.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1070.38 Q
762693  62246385    /   03/06/15    42099   1075.19 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1075.19 Q
762694  62246384    /   03/06/15    42099   1115.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1115.38 Q
763572  62253066    /   03/18/15    42111   890.38  264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 890.38  Q
763574  62253064    /   03/18/15    42111   540 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 540 Q
763805  62255278    /   03/21/15    42114   1520.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1520.38 Q
764809  62260713    /   04/01/15    42125   8190.48 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 3971.88 Q
        2   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     2   7   7   1   3740    3740    Q
        3   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     3   7   7   1   478.59  478.6   Q
765293  62257450    /   03/26/15    42119   540 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e:      6           1   574.31  540 Q
765294  62257449    /   03/26/15    42119   720 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e:      6           1   574.31  720 B
Date: 05/01/    2015                ST. B   ARNABAS O   SPITAL          P   age : 2 
Time: 8:47am                Pay ables Status E  xception    R   pt For 05/01/20 15      R   eport: GARPS    ESB
Voucher Vendor      Vendor  Payment     Po Nb       Total   Total       PO  Inv 
Nbr I   nv Nbr/Ln       Inv Dat e Due Date  Inv Amt Ln Nb       Rec'd   Dist    Inv'd   Price   Price   St
------------    ----------  --- ----------- ----------- --------------  --------    -   --------------- --------    ---------
```

Code:

```
libname niklib '/home/nyioves/Nikfold/';
data myfile4 (drop=checkpt);
length Checkpt $ 5. Vendor $ 30.;
infile '/home/nyioves/Nikfold/Invoice.txt' missover obs=35;
retain Code1 BuyerID Vendor; 
input Checkpt $ @;
   if Checkpt="Buyer" then input Code1 $ BuyerID & $40.;
   if Checkpt="Vendor" then input Vendor : $30.; 
   else if  VoucherNo $ Invno $ seperator $ Vndinvdate mmddyy10.    PaymntDue $ InvAmt $ PONum Status1 $ /
    num1 Las $ letter $ Recvd $ dat $ echar $ date1 $  nnmbr $ totRecd $ totdist invd 
    poprice invprice st2 $; 
run;
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far and where it's failing.

Comment: code added to original post

Comment: Thanks.  So by 'repeating labels', do you mean the 5 bottom lines in the sample data?  Are those always the same?

Comment: yes repeating labels does refer to the bottom 5 lines and yes they repeat the same way throughout. The only exception are the labels that appear at the top. There's 3000 plus rows of data for this file incidentally. In any case, I can just copy and paste over the top set of labels with one of the others and re-upload the file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you're trying to do something like the below.

Note the use of the double @ symbol.  That line of code will read in the input into a temporary variable called `_infile_`.  The double @ symbol will prevent the input cursor from progressing.  This lets us 'look ahead' to see what the line contains before we decide how we want to process it.

Also notice that we read in the buyer and vendor, and retain the values, but we don't output the observation on these lines, we wait for the regular 'transaction' type lines to output.

If it's a line that we want to ignore - ie. the labels, we simply issue another `input` statement to move the input cursor forward to the next line.

EDIT: I should also mention that the `=:` operator is similar to a 'begins-with' operator.  It truncates both strings either side of the operator to the shortest string length and then performs an equality check.

```
data test;
  length buyer_code vendor $200;
  retain buyer_code vendor '';

  infile datalines truncover ;
  input @@;  


  if not (_infile_ =: 'Date:')
  and not (_infile_ =: 'Time:')
  and not (_infile_ =: 'Voucher')
  and not (_infile_ =: 'Nbr I')
  and not (_infile_ =: '-------')
  then do;

    if _infile_ =: 'Buyer Code' then do;
      buyer_code = cats(scan(_infile_,2,':'));
      input;
    end;
    else if _infile_ =: 'Vendor:' then do;
      vendor = cats(scan(_infile_,2,':'));
      input;
    end;
    else do;

      /* REPLACE THESE 2 LINES WITH YOUR INPUT STATEMENT TO INPUT OTHER VARIABLES */
      input  ;
      x = _infile_; 

      output;
    end;
  end;
  else do;
    input; * MOVE INPUT CURSOR TO NEXT LINE WITHOUT ASSIGNING ANYTHING;
  end;
  datalines;
Buyer Code: BLS BETTIE  SM  ITH                                     
Vendor: 8444 DAT    EX- OHMEDA                                      
762100  62245094    /   03/04/15    42097   2142.46 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 2142.46 Q
762101  62243752    /   03/01/15    42094   16001.6 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 16001.6 B
762690  62247150    /   03/07/15    42100   1790.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1790.38 Q
762691  62246387    /   03/06/15    42099   1520.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1520.38 Q
762692  62246386    /   03/06/15    42099   1070.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1070.38 Q
762693  62246385    /   03/06/15    42099   1075.19 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1075.19 Q
762694  62246384    /   03/06/15    42099   1115.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1115.38 Q
763572  62253066    /   03/18/15    42111   890.38  264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 890.38  Q
763574  62253064    /   03/18/15    42111   540 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 540 Q
763805  62255278    /   03/21/15    42114   1520.38 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 1520.38 Q
764809  62260713    /   04/01/15    42125   8190.48 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     1   7   7   1   3971.88 3971.88 Q
        2   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     2   7   7   1   3740    3740    Q
        3   Las t Recvd Dat e: 12/19/14     3   7   7   1   478.59  478.6   Q
765293  62257450    /   03/26/15    42119   540 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e:      6           1   574.31  540 Q
765294  62257449    /   03/26/15    42119   720 264568                          P
        1   Las t Recvd Dat e:      6           1   574.31  720 B
Date: 05/01/    2015                ST. B   ARNABAS O   SPITAL          P   age : 2 
Time: 8:47am                Pay ables Status E  xception    R   pt For 05/01/20 15      R   eport: GARPS    ESB
Voucher Vendor      Vendor  Payment     Po Nb       Total   Total       PO  Inv 
Nbr I   nv Nbr/Ln       Inv Dat e Due Date  Inv Amt Ln Nb       Rec'd   Dist    Inv'd   Price   Price   St
------------    ----------  --- ----------- ----------- --------------  --------    -   --------------- --------    ---------
;
run;
```

Comment: You can also use `in:` in a data step - e.g. `if not(_infile_ in: ('Date:', 'Time:', ...))`

Comment: Robert was awesome. my problem now is that I'm getting data errors e.g. id number 762100 has one detail line item where 764809 has 3 detail line items.

Comment: @NicholasYioves If you're still stuck on the new problem, I'd suggest opening a new question with the specific new issue.  Try and reduce the code and example as much as possible so that just the necessary information is provided.  Also - don't forget to mark this answer as 'accepted' if it answered the question.

Comment: @user667489  Oh nice - I wasn't aware of that.  Looking through the docs, it seems you can suffix any character comparison operator with `:` although I can't think of any operators other than 'equals' or 'in' where it would make sense.